# System.FormatException 'The format of the input string is incorrect

Tags: c#

```
decimal Verbruikt = 0;
decimal res = 0;

// loop through the datagrid and sum the column 
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView.Rows)
    if (item.Cells["Verbruikt"] != null
        && item.Cells["Verbruikt"].Value != null
        && item.Cells["Verbruikt"].Value != System.DBNull.Value)
       Verbruikt += Convert.ToDecimal(item.Cells["Verbruikt"].Value);

res = Convert.ToDecimal(Verbruikt);
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have this code in another project without any problem.

Comment: That's a lot of tentative attempts at conversion. If the column actually *is* a `decimal`, `item.Field<decimal?>("Verbruikt") ?? 0` would do. If not, using the specific type to get it first and then converting as necessary is still a better approach than going through `Convert` blindly. For example, if it's actually a string, going through `Convert` will use the default locale of your system to parse the number, meaning it suddenly matters if there's a `.` or a `,`. `decimal.TryParse` with a `NumberFormatInfo` will catch such issues.

Comment: Start here [CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-6.0). See Remarks: The CultureInfo class is used either directly or indirectly by classes that format, parse, or manipulate culture-specific data, such as String, DateTime, DateTimeOffset, and the numeric types.

Comment: The problem is is 1 empty cell in the datagrigvieuw

Answer (score 0):

[`DataGridViewCell.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) returns an opaque `object`. According to its signature it can return `null`, a `string`, a `decimal`, a `Guid`... it can return literally anything. So your problem boils down to "how can I convert an opaque `object` into a `decimal` without throwing an exception?"

This function will help you do that.

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;

static decimal? TryConvert(object? value, IFormatProvider? formatProvider)
{
    if (value is null)
        return null;
    if (value is decimal d)
        return d;
    if (value is string s && decimal.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, formatProvider, out var parsed))
        return parsed;
    if (value is IConvertible convertible)
    {
        try
        {
            return convertible.ToDecimal(formatProvider);
        }
        catch
        {
            //
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then your code can be written like this:

```cs
decimal res = 0;

// loop through the datagrid and sum the column 
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView.Rows)
{
    var converted = TryConvert(item.Cells["Verbruikt"], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    if (converted.HasValue)
       res += converted.Value;
}
```

Keep in mind what the other folks said in the comments about `CultureInfo`. You might not want the current culture but instead might want `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. The documentation for `CultureInfo` describes the difference.